# Помогите с выбором и установкой редактора GUI для python

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui

я осваиваю python. Так как на работе нет возможности устанавливать приложения в качестве IDE использую Thonny. Появилась необходимость создать приложение с GUI интерфейсом. Подскажите есть ли какое-нибудь приложение, наподобие PyQt disigner, который не нуждается в установке с exe файла. Или есть возможность установить PyQt disigner на домашний компьютер, скопировать папку и запускать его после на рабочем компьютере? Заранее спасибо за советы.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю вашу проблему на работе, а на домашний компьютер вы можете установить что угодно, в т.ч. и `PyQt5` -> `pip install PyQt5` -> `pip install pyqt5-tools`

Comment: Pyqt designer и все остальные конструкторы не являются  необходимым для создания интерефейсов. Можно и в блокноте разметку писать.

Comment: @S.Nick, спасибо, направил меня в нужную сторону) установил pyqt5-tools и в комплекте нашел qt designer.